# Is it possible to unexpose a Rule in Drools?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

Let's say I've a drools file like this,

```
rule "Test Rule 1"
salience 10

when
    $data : Map( this["amount"] >= 1000 && this["quantity"] >=3 )
then
    System.out.println("You've met the Criteria");
end

===========================================================================================

rule "Test Rule 2"
salience 9

when
    $data : Map( this["amount"] >= 1000 )
then
    System.out.println("Quantity Criteria is not met");
end

===========================================================================================

rule "Test Rule 3"
salience 8

when
    $data : Map( this["quantity"] >= 3 )
then
    System.out.println("Amount criteria is not met");
end
```

All these will be present in a single `.drl` file. As like in rule, order of rule will be based on highest Salience number. I need something like,

1) If `Test Rule 1` is satisfied, I dont want further rules to be executed.

2) If `Test Rule 1` is not satisfied, then I dont have to worry, it'll simply execute other rules in order of highest salience.

Is there any option like `hideRule("Test Rule 2", "Test Rule 3")` or `hideRules() - which should unexpose rules waiting to be executed`

I know I can alter my when condition to meet my criteria, but I would like to know if there is any option to `unexpose` a rule in Drools?

Comment: The excessive use of salience and the wish to "turn off" rules after a match are a code smell. What about formulating the conditions for "not met", e.g. `this["amount"] < 1000` when the amount is insufficient?

Comment: @laune, well its just an example. I will be handling all those conditions when implementing. I want to know if it could be possible to do what I'm looking for..

Comment: Look into rule attribute activation-group.

Answer (score 0):

add `drools.halt();` at the end of your `Test Rule 1`

Answer (score 0):

An activation group will solve this:

> An activation group is a set of rules bound together by the same "activation-group" rule attribute. In this group only one rule can fire, and after that rule has fired all the other rules are cancelled from the agenda. The clear() method can be called at any time, which cancels all of the activations before one has had a chance to fire.

Adding `activation-group "groupName"` to each of your rules should produce the behavior you are expecting.